# Dynare Installing problems: umfpack

Tags: matlab, umfpack

I'm trying to compile dynare 4.4.2 on my rosa linux r3 (64bit) for matlab R2013a. The configure step is

```
./configure --with-matlab=/media/Docs/Studium/matlab MATLAB_VERSION=8.1
```

But I'm getting the error

```
configure: error: Can't find UMFPACK
configure: error: ./configure failed for mex/build/octave
```

I've been trying it with

```
 --with-umfpack=/usr/include/suitesparse
```

, but the error is still remaining.
Umfpack is installed (lib64umfpack-devel, lib64umfpack5.6.1 packages), so I have no idea what to do. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!